# Asp.Net MVC 5 route not getting hit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have this in my RouteConfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);


routes.MapRoute(
    name: "StoreSearch",
    url: "{storeName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Store" }
);
```

Basically I have a 2nd route so if I type in `localhost:9000/facebook` there is no such controller by the name of `facebook` so my 2nd router should pickup `facebook` as the `storeName` and hit my `Search` controller's `Store` action. But at the moment I get 404.

Any ideas how do I fix this?

Comment: route conflict because those routes are too general. the first one will match any attempt at trying to hit the second route.

Comment: Thank you. What do you suggest as a alternative to implement what I need?

Comment: Which controller and action would you want to execute?

Comment: Basically, it would work normally for example if I have Home controller it should go to Home/Action - pretty standard stuff but if I type in walmart, facebook etc I do not have it's controller in my project so 1st route should not get hit it should take walmart as the storeName parameter and call my Search controller's Store action. But if I had the Facebook controller then obviously that should get hit. Let me know if I am unclear.

Comment: So you want to when to call  Search controller's Store action. user execute `{host}/facebook` or `{host}/walmart `

Comment: Right sir. host/facebook should call my Search controller's store action but facebook / walmart etc is dynamic. It could be any store. Basically if controller does not exist it should call Search's controller's store action

Comment: Tip: Decorate your Action with [Route("facebook")]

Comment: Nope. If you read my question storename is actually a variable in the action. Facebook is not hardcoded. It could be anything walmart etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have specific set of stores or a way to verify them you can add a constraint to the route.

To add a generic constraint with match predicate

```
public class ServerRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly Func<Uri, bool> _predicate;

    public ServerRouteConstraint(Func<Uri, bool> predicate)
    {
        this._predicate = predicate;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName,
        RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return this._predicate(httpContext.Request.Url);
    }
}
```

and then in the route add a paramater

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "StoreSearch",
   url: "{storeName}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Store" }, constraints: 
//this could be new { controller ="pattern" } 
new {
     serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraint(url =>
     {
//this will check that the route starts with a specific string in this case Settings
         return url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/Settings",
      StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
     })
   });
```

For examples check: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/route-constraints-in-mvc/

Also, routes should be added from most specific to most general.

Answer (score 0):

You should place any custom route above the `Default` route.

Just swap the order and you good to go

```
//before default route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "StoreSearch",
    url: "{storeName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Store" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: That was not as easy. I already tried this. But then if I have a Home controller then also my Search/Store is triggered. I want that if the controller exists then use that otherwise use my Search/Store action.